# Filament Group Menu controls not working in JQuery 1.4/JQueryUI 1.8?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I downloaded the menu from Filament Group, which was designed for JQuery 1.3.2. I tried it in JQuery 1.4, and it works, but the rest of the page gets messed up. Any help would be appreciated.
The widgets that do not work are autocomplete and checkbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind... Figured it out myself. I am using JQueryUI 1.8.4, which has its own "menu" function. So, I modified the fg.menu.js file to change the "menu" function to the "menuize" function. This worked and I'm sorry!

Answer (score 2):

dude, you rock! I spent hours on this problem. the filament group menu clashes with jquery ui autolookup. Simply rename the fg.menu.js menu call and it's fixed! THANKS!!

in fg.menu.js:
$.fn.menu = function(options){
becomes:
$.fn.mymenu = function(options){

call is then:
$('#mybutton').mymenu({ content: $('#myMenuContent').html(), backLink: false });

Comment: Glad to be of help. It doesn't matter what you rename it to, as long as you actually use that name in your $(document).ready() handler.